# Serialization in OrientDb

Tags: java, serialization, orientdb

When I create a Document and save it in OrientDb using java.Does the saving the document and retrieving the document includes Serialization or marshalling.If not is there any new technique used by OrientDb?Is the new Technique better than serialization in terms of time taken to insert and retrieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Serialization is the process to convert objects to a byte array (or better to a sequence of bits)**. (Serialization and marshalling are different terms to show the same process. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization))

If you need to save objects in any form (database, file, stream) you need to serialize them.

OrientDb has its own implementation to serialize and deserialize objects. They uses internal code to do that instead of external libraries to be more efficient and to know exactly how the data are stored.

It is possible to know more about how OrientDb serialize data taking a look to their [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Record-Schemaless-Binary-Serialization.html). I don't know if this is the form of data that are used to save records on the database or only used as network interchange format.

Comment: Can I know about ODocument.Whether the references of this are serialized.So the question boils down to whether all the primitives in OrientDb that Start with 'O'(like ODocument,Oclass,OSchema.) are traditional classes or not?If so,According to what u mentioned above to save these classes instances from memory to Database serialization process is used?Can u please confirm?If there is any supporting links regarding this,please provide them.

Comment: I edited the answer with a link to the OrientDb serialization documentation